# how to make a kedro pipeline take configurable input dataframes?

Tags: kedro

I have created a workflow in kedro made of different data science processing pipelines. These pipelines are tested independently.

When i run a particular kedro pipeline  in stand alone fashion, the pipeline takes its input from a CSV file.

In the production environment, the pipelines need to be stitched together. In production, when i am running this pipeline(PL1) together with another pipeline (PL0) , I would like the pipeline (PL1) take its input from pipeline (PL0) .

So how to make the input to a kedro pipeline configurable depending on runtime option? Runtime option can be either standalone or integration.

I appreciate any example code to accomplish the same.

Answer (score 1):

As an example, create a new Kedro sample project with `kedro new --starter spaceflights`. If you accept all of the default prompts, you will end up with a project in the `new-kedro-project` directory. Inside that folder, you will find `src/new_kedro_project/pipeline_registry.py` contains two pipelines (`dp` and `ds`) as well as their combination, the `__default__` pipeline. `dp` and `ds` are analogous to your `PL0` and `PL1`, respectively.

First, let's allow the `ds` pipeline to be run in a `standalone` environment. There is one dataset input to the pipeline, `model_input_table`, for which we define a catalog entry in the `standalone` environment's catalog, `conf/standalone/catalog.yml`:

```yaml
model_input_table:
  type: pandas.CSVDataSet
  filepath: data/03_primary/example_model_input_table.csv
  layer: primary
```

Now, you can run your `ds` pipeline in the standalone environment with `kedro run --env standalone --pipeline ds`, provided you've placed your sample data in `data/03_primary/example_model_input_table.csv`.

In the production environment, you could run your end-to-end pipeline with `kedro run --env production`, assuming you created a `production` folder under `conf`. If it's empty, this is almost equivalent to just using the default `base` environment (the different lies in whether something in the `local` env is considered).

In reality, you would probably change a lot more paths based on the environment, quite possibly using [templated configuration](https://kedro.readthedocs.io/en/0.17.5/04_kedro_project_setup/02_configuration.html#template-configuration). You can read a lot more about all of this, including [additional configuration environments](https://kedro.readthedocs.io/en/0.17.5/04_kedro_project_setup/02_configuration.html#additional-configuration-environments), in the [Configuration](https://kedro.readthedocs.io/en/0.17.5/04_kedro_project_setup/02_configuration.html) section in the official docs.